# Google Place Detail API returns incorrect JSON

Tags: json, google-api, google-places-api

I am using google place details API and it return object within object, incorrect json but data is correct.
Here is output

```
{{
   "html_attributions": [],
    "result": {
    "address_components": [
    ........... // more details commented here
   "status": "OK"
}}
```

According to https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details , it should be

```
{
  "html_attributions": [],
  "result": {
   .....
```

I am also adding default header as "application/json".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some problem how I was receiving the data..no problem with google API